# SignUp Button Not Working While Handling RootViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, nsuserdefaults, rootviewcontroller

I'm building an iOS app using a Storyboard. The root view controller is a Home View Controller. I'm creating the login/logout process, and it's mostly working fine, but I've got a few issues. I need to know the BEST way to set all this up.
When I tap on login and logout the app works fine but when I tap on Sign up Nothing works I have created a navigation controller too.
I'm just not sure what the best method is at this point.

I'm Giving you My Details

**This Is MY Switcher Class For Managing View**

```
import UIKit

class Switcher {

static func updateRootViewController() {

    let status = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: Constants.kUserDefaults.isSignIn)
    var rootViewController : UIViewController?

    #if DEBUG
    print(status)
    #endif

    if (status == true) {
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainTabBarController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardID.homeViewController) as! HomeViewController
        rootViewController = mainTabBarController
    }  else {
    
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let signInViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardID.signInViewController) as! SignInViewController
        rootViewController = signInViewController
    }

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController

   }

   }
```

**My App Delegate**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    Switcher.updateRootViewController()
    return true
}
```

**Sign UP Button**

```
@IBAction func signUpBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let signUpVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegistrationViewController") as? RegistrationViewController else {
        return
    }
    print("Register Tapped")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the your rootViewController does not have a UINavigationViewController set up, for neither of the Viewcontrollers.
what you need to do is instead of instantiating like this:

```
    if (status == true) {
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainTabBarController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardID.homeViewController) as! HomeViewController
        rootViewController = mainTabBarController
    }  else {

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let signInViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardID.signInViewController) as! SignInViewController
        rootViewController = signInViewController
}
```

You need to instantiate a UINavigationController which it's root is these like the following

```
        if (status == true) {
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainTabBarController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardID.homeViewController) as! HomeViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainTabBarController)
        rootViewController = navigationController
    }  else {

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let signInViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardID.signInViewController) as! SignInViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: signInViewController)

        rootViewController = navigationController
    }
```

Now your    `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpVC, animated: true)` will work since the "navigationController" exists.